# How to assign visual block selection to mouse's middle button in vim?

Tags: vim

I want to assign visual block selection to middle button of mouse. Hence, holding middle button means visual block selection is activated, release - stop to select and leave the selection for further actions. Is it possible?

I find no information about assigning middle button in `:help` and it seems there are only several predefined scenarios how we can use the mouse.

Comment: Goood...I tried to assign by `nmap <MiddleDrag> <C-v>`, but it only go into visual block and don't make any further selection while moving a cursor. It seems I've missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get into the visual block mode, you need to make a quadruple click. So you can assign it to the middle button. Then you need to assign a drag to make an area.

```
noremap <MiddleMouse> <4-LeftMouse>
noremap <MiddleDrag> <LeftDrag>
```

should be sufficient. If you need to get in the select block mode after releasing the middle button, you can add

```
noremap <MiddleRelease> <C-g>
```

See [`:help mouse-using`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/term.txt.html#mouse-using).